# threeJS Trackball Controls camera rotation

Tags: javascript, camera, rotation, three.js, perspectivecamera

I've been using threejs for a while for the 3D of an image-based modeling application ( [vmtklab.orobix.com](http://vmtklab.orobix.com) ).
For camera rotation/translation/zooming I am using TrackballControls.js.

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.5;
controls.target.set( pos.x, pos.y, pos.z );
```

I'm used to camera movement as in vtk ( paraview, etc ) and I can not find how to replicate this behavior in threejs.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ugxbktLt/5/

Basically, if I click on the canvas in the center and I move the mouse along the y axis the camera rotates as expected.
If I click on the canvas in a point which is distant from the center ( example on the right side of the cube ), the camera rotates in two directions and not only following my mouse movement.

I was expecting that the camera rotates following only the vector between the start point ( mousedown ) and end point generated by mouse movement and NOT considering the position of the start point. It seems rotating around a sphere.

Any suggestions?
Best regards
Simone

Comment: Yes, the simulated trackball is in the center of the canvas. You appear to prefer to imagine the simulated trackball as being repositioned directly under the mouse on mousedown events.

Comment: Thank you but I cannot understand how to manage the getMouseProjectionOnBall in order to do not always consider the center of the canvas as its center. Any ideas? tnx

Comment: No, sorry - no quick fix ideas. I like your idea, BTW.

Comment: I decided to implement a new control from scratch following the VTK camera controls style. I will submit a pull request asap.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e0s61k8f/1/

Answer (score 4):

Fixed:
With SymmetricTrackballControls.js we can rotate camera independently from the position of the mouse on the canvas but considering only the mouse movement.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/6096